# compressionMinSize does not work on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, http, tomcat, compression, gzip

I want to enable gzip compression on tomcat6 for files larger than 2048 bytes. I therefore set the Connector:
`<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"

               connectionTimeout="20000"

               redirectPort="8443"

               compression="on"

               compressionMinSize="2048"

               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,application/javascript,application/json"
/>`

However, the compressionMinSize parameter does not seem to work. In the Response Header I always get:
`Content-Encoding:gzip`
even for small responses (e.g. request size 376B, content size 213B)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `compressionMinSize` option is only present in Tomcat 7.0 and up. For Tomcat 6.0 you should use `compression="2048"` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: According to the documentation you're right and I've fixed attribute name, but after restarting the server nothing changed. Small responses are still compressed.

Comment: Tomcat does have some minor yet annoying bugs, which are fixed at later versions. So, if you can, upgrade to the latest version first.
Also, try to also use `compressionMinSize="2048"` which is actually handled in the code but not shown in the documentation. Having said that, my configurations (Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7) both work properly with the recommended settings, so there may be something special about your setup (valves, filters etc)...